# I am unable to install wireshark

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, wireshark

On running the command `sudo apt install wireshark-qt`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wireshark-qt : Depends: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                Depends: libwireshark11 (>= 2.5.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libwscodecs2 (>= 2.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: wireshark-common (= 2.6.8-1~ubuntu16.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libqt5multimedia5-plugins but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You haven't said what release you are on, but packages appear to match those requirements for all supported (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libqt5multimedia5)  Have you tried `sudo apt -f install` and verified you have no broken packages from prior installs?  Also telling us your release may help.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise running the following ...

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
```

Let me know if any errors occur from the above.

Comment: On running the first command i got 1 error:  rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/partial': Is a directory
And several warnings while this sudo apt-get upgrade -y like:W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven_mec.bin for module amdgpu